# select data attribute of option using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using a jQuery Plugin [select2.js](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/). how can i select data attribute of selected option using jQuery.

here is the code

```
<select class="select2">
  <option data-id="1" value="2"> CASE 1 </option>
  <option data-id="2" value="2"> CASE 1 </option>
  <option data-id="3" value="2"> CASE 1 </option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.select2').select2();

   $('.select2').click(function(){
       //alert($(this).val());

   });
});
```

How i can get `data-id` of selected option using jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has the same logic as select element.
You can use default selectors.

```
$('.select2').change(function(){
    alert($(this).find('option:selected').data('id'))
});
```

But i recommend you to use change event instead of click on select boxes.

Answer (score 0):

this will give you the data attribute

```
$(this).data("id")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on change event, Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nishantnawarkhede/L79h6Lr4/)

```
$(function() { 
    $(".select2").change(function(){ 
        var element = $(this).find('option:selected'); 
        var id= element.attr("data-id"); 
        alert(id);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find selected option using `:selected` selector and then use `.data()` to get/set data attribute value. you should also use change event instead of click event for select element:

```
$('.select2').change(function(){
  var selecteddataid = $(this).find('option:selected').data('id');
});
```